# Dynamically add form input fields and store values with Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, html, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm working with a Product & Price model. My products table has an id and name column, while my prices table has an id,product_id,cost and date column. The product_id on the prices table references the id on the products table. My form displays a field for each product so that the user will then enter the price from time to time. My challenge is how to handle the request data so that the price will correspond to the product_id. Below is the code i have written so far

Form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ url('/home/prices') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
@if(isset($products) && !empty($products))
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="product_id[]" value="{{ $product->id }}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2" for="{{ $product->name }}">{{ ucwords($product->name) }}</label>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cost[]">
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@else
    Sorry, no product available currently.
@endif

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
</form>
```

PriceController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
//dd($request);
foreach ($request->input('cost') as $cost) {
    Price::create([
        'product_id' => $request->product_id,
        'date' => Carbon::now(),
        'cost' => $cost,
        'trend' => 0
    ]);
}

return redirect('/home');
}
```

This what i get when i dump the request data
[image]

Of course my code throws up this error
`at Builder->insertGetId(array('product_id' => array('1', '2', '3'), 'date' => object(Carbon), 'cost' => '14.05', 'trend' => 0, 'updated_at' => '2017-08-07 11:21:47', 'created_at' => '2017-08-07 11:21:47'), 'id')`

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($request->input('cost') as $key=>$cost) {

    Price::create([
        'product_id' => $request->product_id[$key],
        'date' => Carbon::now(),
        'cost' => $cost,
        'trend' => 0
    ]);
}
```

as you can see the whole array is getting passed in the id of products, so you need to mention a particular id for which you need to insert

Answer (score 1):

You can use concept of index or key/value pair in array of input like this:

Try this,

```
foreach ($request->input('cost') as $key=>$cost) {
    Price::create([
        'product_id' => $request->product_id[$key],
        'date' => Carbon::now(),
        'cost' => $cost,
        'trend' => 0
    ]);
}
```

This will save your data like

```
1 -> 14.05
2 -> 13.75
3 -> 12.99
```

Hope you understand.