# Laravel update one to many relationship data

Tags: laravel, sql-update, laravel-8

The blade

```
@foreach ($employee->educations as $education)

    <x-update_input label="university_name" type="text" name="university_name"
    value="{{ $education->university_name }}">
        University Name
    </x-update_input>

    <x-update_input label="major" type="text" name="major"
    value="{{ $education->major }}">
        Major
    </x-update_input>

    <x-update_input label="duration_start" type="date" name="duration_start"
    value="{{ $education->duration_start }}">
        Start Date
    </x-update_input>

    <x-update_input label="duration_end" type="date" name="duration_end"
    value="{{ $education->duration_end }}">
        End Date
    </x-update_input>
    

@endforeach
```

This is in my controller update

```
 $education=EmployeeEducation::find($id);
        foreach($employee->educations as $education){
         
            $education->university_name = $request->university_name;
            $education->major = $request->major;
            $education->duration_start = $request->duration_start;
            $education->duration_end = $request->duration_end;
            $education->save();
        }
```

This is one to many relationships, how can I update the data. There are total three universities and how can I update data for all universities? I do like above, it will update all the data as the last university's data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically add form input fields and store values with Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545794/dynamically-add-form-input-fields-and-store-values-with-laravel-5)

Comment: @ zahid hasan emon sorry,I don't understand,could u please explain how to use it in my case? thank you

Comment: you have to use array input and then loop over that to insert those into database.

Comment: @zahid hasan emon this way cannot use for update ,it will show this error                                        
      param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request

Non static method 'update' should not be called statically.

Comment: how are you using it??

Comment: foreach($employee->educations as $key=>$education){
          EmployeeEducation::update([
                'university_name' => $request->university_name[$key],
                'major' => $request->major[$key],
                'duration_start' => $request->duration_start[$key],
                'duration_end' => $request->duration_startr[$key]

             ] );@ zahid hasan emon

Comment: you can't use update directly on model class. you have to use it in object like so `$education->update()`

Comment: foreach ($employee->educations as $key=> $education) {
              $education->update([
                    'university_name' => $request->university_name[$key],
                    'major' => $request->major[$key],
                    'duration_start' => $request->duration_start[$key],
                    'duration_end' => $request->duration_end[$key]
                    

                 ] );@ zahid hasan emon  it's still cannot

Comment: what's not working now??

Comment: @zahid hasan emon
it will not update the new input to the database, update fail

Comment: what error you are getting?? are you using array input??

Comment: @zahid hasan emon
I am using the way that show in the blade code and there was not showing any errors,but just fail update

Comment: then i fear you are not using the code correctly. there are lots of similar questions and tutorials out there. you should try something yourself.